# CSS effect two elements

Tags: css

I'm trying to affect two elements, the event-thumbnail `img:hover` will effect also `.event-date` .
when I'm trying to do something like `.event-date+.event-date`
its effect only on the `.event-date`.

```css
 .event-list .event-thumbnail img{
     display: block;
     transition: 0.8s;     
    }

    .event-list .event-thumbnail img:hover +.event-date {
      transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    }

    .event-thumbnail .event-date{
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     background:#07A2DD;
     color:#FFF;
     width: 60px;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 10px 0;
     line-height: 1;
     font-weight: 600;
    }
```

```html
<div id="latest-events">

   
         <h1><a href="http://sd.esy.es/category/events/">events</a></h1>

         
          <div class="event-list clearfix">
           
           <figure class="event-thumbnail">
      <a href="http://sd.esy.es/event2/">
            <img src="http://sd.esy.es/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/1-135x100.png" alt="2">
            
             <div class="event-date">
       <span class="event-date-day">10</span>
       <span class="event-date-month">oc</span>
       </div>
            </a>
     </figure> 

     <div class="event-detail">
            <h4 class="event-title">
             <a href="http://sd.esy.es/event2/">2</a>
            </h4>

            <div class="event-excerpt">
             text

           </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         
          <div class="event-list clearfix">
           
           <figure class="event-thumbnail">
      <a href="http://sd.esy.es/event3/">
            <img src="http://sd.esy.es/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/1-135x100.png" alt=" 3">
            
             <div class="event-date">
       <span class="event-date-day">10</span>
       <span class="event-date-month">oc</span>
       </div>
            </a>
     </figure> 

     <div class="event-detail">
            <h4 class="event-title">
             <a href="http://sd.esy.es/event3/"> 3</a>
            </h4>

            <div class="event-excerpt">
             text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

           </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         
          <div class="event-list clearfix">
           
           <figure class="event-thumbnail">
      <a href="http://sd.esy.es/event1/">
            <img src="http://sd.esy.es/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/1-135x100.png" alt=" 1">
            
             <div class="event-date">
       <span class="event-date-day">10</span>
       <span class="event-date-month">feb</span>
       </div>
            </a>
     </figure> 

     <div class="event-detail">
            <h4 class="event-title">
             <a href="http://sd.esy.es/event1/">1</a>
            </h4>

            <div class="event-excerpt">
            some text            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: add your html code as well.

Comment: Do you want to transform them both or do you want to execute the transform on both ev

Comment: @Ivaro18 Yes, i want to transform them both.

Comment: then take a look at Dzhakhar Ukhaev his answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
.event-thumbnail img,
.event-thumbnail img + .event-date {
    transition: 0.8s;
}
.event-thumbnail img:hover,
.event-thumbnail img:hover + .event-date {
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The same properties can be applied to multiple selectors at once by separating the selectors with a comma, as in the following:

```
selectorA,
selectorB,
selectorC {
    property: value;
    property: value;
    property: value;
}
```

Comment: But I think he wants to transform both the image and the .event-date on hovering the image

Comment: Easy: `img:hover, .img:hover + .event-date{   }`

Comment: .event-list .event-thumbnail img{
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.event-list .event-thumbnail img:hover, .img:hover + .event-date{ 
transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
   
}

Comment: `.event-list .event-thumbnail img{ transition: 0.8s; } .event-list .event-thumbnail img:hover, .img:hover + .event-date{ transform: scale(1.1,1.1); }`  only effect the image and not the second div

Comment: and  `.event-list .event-thumbnail img:hover, .event-list .event-thumbnail  .img:hover + .event-date{ transform: scale(1.1,1.1); }`?

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine, see my [example](http://codepen.io/Dzhakhar/pen/yaQGak).

```
div:hover + p {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    ...
}
```

Maybe the `transform: scale(1.1,1.1);` doesn't work? Try to set primitive styles to make sure your selector works right. For example `background: red;`.